# Django development server won't run

Tags: python, django, server

I'm using Python 3.4.2 and Django 1.7.1

I've been able to create a folder called mysite with its content like shown in the tutorial.

But when I run the command manage.py runserver nothing happens:

```
C:\Users\thEpuQ8f\Dropbox\zephyrus>manage.py runserver
```

I get following message in the command line:

```
Usage: manage.py subcommand [options] [args]

Options:
  -v VERBOSITY, --verbosity=VERBOSITY
                    Verbosity level; 0=minimal output, 1=normal output,
                    2=verbose output, 3=very verbose output
  --settings=SETTINGS   The Python path to a settings module, e.g.
                    "myproject.settings.main". If this isn't provided, the
                    DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE environment variable will be
                    used.
  --pythonpath=PYTHONPATH
                    A directory to add to the Python path, e.g.
                    "/home/djangoprojects/myproject".
  --traceback           Raise on exception
  --no-color            Don't colorize the command output.
  --version             show program's version number and exit
  -h, --help            show this help message and exit

Type 'manage.py help <subcommand>' for help on a specific subcommand.

Available subcommands:

# and so forth
```

Comment: Is pythonpath set? Try python manage.py runserver

Comment: I get: `C:\Users\thEpuQ8f\Dropbox\zephyrus>python manage.py runserver 'python' is not recognized as an internal or external command, operable program or batch file.` Doesen't seem to work at all.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You probably don't have the correct PYTHONPATH.

You know what has worked for me really well on windows.

> My Computer > Properties > Advanced System Settings > Environment
>    Variables >

Then under system variables I create a new Variable called PythonPath.

> C:\Python34;C:\Python34\Lib;C:\Python34\DLLs;

Where Python34 is the folder of the Python. I don't know what's the correct folder name for python3. When you install the Python with installer, it should create PYTHONPATH automatically. So worst case scenario is that you just reinstall it.

[image]

Source: https://stackoverflow.com/a/4855685/73010

Answer (score 0):

Try this command:

```
python manage.py runserver
```

Adding `python` in front of your command will run your python file.

If it produces errors, then make sure that python is installed and python install dir is listed in your `PATH` environment variable.

When it runs, try opening this [URL](https://127.0.0.1:8000) in your web browser of choice to see if it works.

Then you should see a page like this:
[image]

Comment: Python3 not python